# iSeries recovery from SAVSYS media

Tags: ibm, ibm-midrange

I am trying to recover a AS/400 system (8203-E4A) using SAVSYS media (DAT 72 media / IBM i 7.1). However, when I attempt to IPL using the instructions provided on IBM's site, I get a code of B2004158 LP=00001.

I am using the ASMI via serial. There is no HMC.

Last few codes:

```
B2003110 LP=00001
B2D03002
C2008118
D200C300
B2004158 LP=00001
```

Here is my boot configuration per the ASMI menu:

```
Power On/Off System
Current system power state: Off
Current firmware boot side: Permanent
Current system server firmware state: Not running

 1. System boot speed (Currently: Hyper)
 2. Firmware boot side for the next boot (Currently: Permanent)
 3. System operating mode (Currently: Manual)
 4. AIX/Linux partition mode boot (Currently: Continue to operating system)
 5. Server firmware start policy (Currently: Running (Auto-Start Always))
 6. System power off policy (Currently: Automatic)
 7. i5/OS partition mode boot (Currently: D)
 8. Power on
 9. Default Partition Environment (Currently: i5/OS)
```

I am not an AS/400 expert, so I am kind of lost with how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/P8DEA/p8eai/B2004158.htm)

> This error indicates a failure during a search for the load source.

My guess, you're either not setting the system to IPL from the tape, or the tape drive is not configured as an alternate IPL device.

Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with ASMI (my admin backgroud was with a 5250 terminal emulator as the console.)

I'd suggest joining the [midrange mailing list](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/MIDRANGE-L) and asking your question there.  There's not that many midrange folks on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same box as you. I don't know if you have the RAID5-Option I have. After a while I found out that I need to set the alternate IPL device to the same device (RAID Controller!) as the primary: The CD-ROM is also connected to the RAID-Controller (logically). I think the SAS Tape drive is also connected to this controller (because it's plugged into the backplane).

Based on the findings of @Charles, check this settings (Primary and alternate IPL device). Your posted ASMI settings look correct, though. Especially IPL type. So I think you're "just" missing to allocate the proper IPL device(s) to the LPAR.

I can't tell you how to do that in ASMI, though. Especially console handling without any OS installed is somewhat annoying, so I opted for a HMC which also made it easier for me to allocate and relocate resources between LPARs.